# XMPP connect and receive

Tags: xmpp

I have been working on a text and voice chat application, and I am looking at XMPP. I visited http://www.xmpp.org and found an open source server and clients. the clients don't seem to provide me the complete flexibility I need, so I need to create one of my own.

I need to know the following:

How can I connect to an XMPP server(I have installed Openfire)?
My basic aim is just to send XML and receive the response from Openfire.

What XML do I need to send, and how do I send and receive it?

Answer (score 0):

See [RFC 3920](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3920.html#sec-4), section 4.8 Simplified Stream Examples

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [libxmpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmpp/) for one possible route.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of [client libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) for XMPP which will provide you this functionality.  Choose one in your language of choice that supports the features you want to use.

There are probably a couple for each language and you can search for the effectiveness, support and popularity of the relevant ones.